# JSON conversion

Tags: android, json

I wanted to know how to convert the http response from the server in a proper parsable JSON array

```
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(
                    "http://riffre.com/chatapp/search.php?format=json");
            postRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            responsesrch = httpClient.execute(postRequest, responseHandler);

            Log.v("search response", responsesrch);
```

this is my code where I post a few parameters in form of name value pairs to the server 
and the value of `responseserch` that I get is

```
{"users":[{"user":{"city":"gurgaon","username":"zxc","userid":"6","gender":"Male","images":"0"}},{"user":{"city":"gurgaon","username":"tarun","userid":"5","gender":"Male","images":"0"}},{"user":{"city":"gurgaon","username":"vips","userid":"4","gender":"Male","images":"0"}},{"user":{"city":"gurgaon","username":"rah","userid":"3","gender":"Male","images":"0"}},{"user":{"city":"gurgaon","username":"aak","userid":"2","gender":"Male","images":"0"}}]}
```

and this is in string format ,So I wanted to know how can I convert this string into a json array , I don't know yet how I must use Input stream and all those entities, Any help therefore would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please look this , it is simple

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

convert IS to String

```
 try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
```

convert String to Json Object

```
try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
```

get Array from Object

```
 // Getting Array of Contacts
    JSONArray  contacts = json.getJSONArray("users");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

1. [GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)
2. [JackSon](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes)

If you want to use the default json from json.org then import  `org.json.JSONArray;` and you could do :

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(yourJsonString);
```

See: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample from my working code:

```
   jArray = new JSONArray(result);
   JSONObject json_data = null;
   double[] tempLong = null;
   double[] tempLat = null;
   for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
       json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
       tempLong = new double[jArray.length()];
       tempLat = new double[jArray.length()];
       tempLong[i] = json_data.getDouble("longtitude");
       tempLat[i] = json_data.getDouble("latitude");
   }
```

I'm sure you can adapt it for your needs

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert Java Objects from/to JSON, you can have a look on : [google-gson Java library](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Answer (score 1):

With two lines of code

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(responsesrch.toString());
JSONArray jArr=jObj.getJSONArray("users");
```